# How to acces the twitter user profile link?

Tags: twitter

I need to access the twitter user profile url, after authentication of each users i wants to take their profile urls. i wants to know that how to do this in wordpress. Is there any plugins available or how to do this feature in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

You can take below steps as guideline.
After logged in user, you can display one form to add twitter URL.

After submitting that form by user, add this form info by using `add_user_meta` for logged in user.

Reference; [`add_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta)

And added information will get by [`get_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

Comment: I don't want fill the fields by user, user click on the connect to twitter button, after login it will auto get the user profile URL.